# Suggestions for Document Archive Site

Tags: cms, tags

I have been charged with documenting our organizations paper assets that roll back to the early 1600's and was wondering if there was a online platform already existing for this type of website. It would mainly consist of scanned versions of the documents, it's transcript (as some of the writing used - it my as well be written in double dutch!) and some method of tagging each document to a particular title.

My initial thoughts were along the lines of a Joomla system, with relevant tagging and other plugins installed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would look into Box.net
They offer versioning of documents, and platforms for sharing docs.
Of course i am refering to software files such as excel and word.

If they are scanned as PDF or images box.net will handle that also.
Take a look at them.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a product already geared towards document management instead of customizing something.
Among open-source products, I recommend Alfresco (http://www.alfresco.com/products/dm/).

If the information is extensive and a matter of legal issues you might want to check out the ECM-market.